# MySQL ORDER BY and date fields having unpredictable results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a very strange issue at the moment with PHP and MySQL.

I have a table of data which I'm trying to sort by date. but coming accross two strange things:

1. When I use PHP pagination (Using LIMIT in SQL) in my app, and there is a few records with the same date, but over two pages, when I scroll to the second page the ordering has changed, and as a result you see some records that were on the first page, and some records you don't see at all!
2. I went about debugging this by printing the SQL command and the IDs of the rows returned. I n copied and pasted one of the SQL commands PHP printed, and inserted that command directly into phpMyAdmin, and it returned the value set in a different order!

This is my command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM orders as a, companies as b, orderProducts as e 
WHERE a.companyId = b.id AND a.id = e.orderId AND a.deleted = 0 AND a.id <> 0 
ORDER BY a.dateReceived DESC 
LIMIT 45, 15
```

The command seems to work as expected when done through phpMyAdmin; it retains the same order, but through PHP it changes it.

This is my code for printing the IDs so I don't think it's something in PHP.

```
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( 'A mysql error has occured: ' . mysql_error(). $query );
$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ids[]=$row['id'];
}
if( $_GET['debug'] == "true" ) {        
    echo "Query: ".$query." IDs: ";
    print_r( $ids );    
}
```

Maybe it's to do with those joins?

Any ideas?

Comment: you are storing date in which data type?

Comment: ok, so its a problem of pagination, can you show me a full code of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM orders as a, companies as b, orderProducts as e 
WHERE a.companyId = b.id AND a.id = e.orderId AND a.deleted = 0 AND a.id <> 0 
ORDER BY a.dateReceived DESC 
LIMIT 45, 15
```

is doing a `distinct` on `id`, but then ordering by `dateReceived`.  In most dialects of SQL, this would be an error, because the `order by` column is not available after the `distinct`.  MySQL chooses an arbitrary value, which is probably the cause of your problem.

The following uses explicit aggregation and `max()` to fix this:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM orders as a, companies as b, orderProducts as e 
WHERE a.companyId = b.id AND a.id = e.orderId AND a.deleted = 0 AND a.id <> 0 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY max(a.dateReceived) DESC 
LIMIT 45, 15;
```